# Ogg Vorbis/FLAC Support for OS X 10.10

Tags: itunes, macos, quicktime, flac

I used to playback Ogg Vorbis and FLAC files (in iTunes) with this QuickTime plugin: https://www.xiph.org/quicktime/

But this no longer seems to work in OS X 10.10 (probably also in 10.9, I don't have many Ogg files/FLAC files, so I use it not very often). Is there any possiblity to playback Ogg Vorbis/FLAC in iTunes? Using another player like VLC works of course...